# Accessing "level" of scope in Swift for more meaningful debug strings

Tags: swift, scope

I'm looking for a way to dynamically determine the "level" of scope that the code is being executed at.

For example, if class z has functions x and y:

If function x gets called by class z, print statements will appear identical to if it gets called from within function y, or from within a function within function y.

I want to include extra whitespace per "level" of scope, so that when I print to indicate a function is being called, it prints with indentation that is one tab more than the code that called it. To do that, I would need to determine the "level" of scope somehow. I could do this manually, but that would be more painful than it would probably be worth.

Does Swift do this automatically anywhere that I can access?

*edit*
I just realized that what I'm looking for may not technically be the "level" of scope, so much as the "level" of "called functions". Like, I want a value that will += 1 for every "{" that begins a function and -= 1 for every "}" that ends a function, if that makes sense, so I can multiply a "\t" by that value and put the result at the beginning of all print statements in that function block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in mechanism for what you want. You could load a stack trace and build what you want from that, but that would be a fair amount of work.

Alternatively, you could create a static variable `callDepth`, increment it on entry to every function, and decrement it at the end of every function (or in a defer block defined at the beginning of every function so it works even if you have return statements at various places in your functions.)

Then you could use the `callDepth` variable to determine how many tabs to use in logging your function data.

Comment: Good idea with the defer block for doing it manually! I'd forgotten that was possible.

Comment: I ended up using a custom static variable and the defer block. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a ready-made solution, here's what I did exactly:

From early on, I had the first line of every function have this:

```
print("\t\(#function)  \(self.classForCoder)  \(#file.getLastPath())  \(Thread.current)")
```

This gave me useful debug information that was indented past more specific print debug statements. It also didn't need to be customized per function, I could just copy/paste. Based on input from the accepted answer above to keep track of scope, I made a quick stack struct just for tracking function names and printing them in a scope-conscious way: https://gist.github.com/austenstrine/38f27e32dc1248d16d44f1eac1af67d5

I used that struct to make a static variable:

```
class AppData //in a separate file
{
    static var funcStack = ScopedPrintableStack()
}
```

I used the size of the stack to determine scope in the print statement. Now I have this at the top of every function:

```
AppData.funcStack.push(#function)
print(String(repeating: "\t", count: AppData.funcStack.count)+"\(#function)  \(self.classForCoder)  \(#file.getLastPath())  \(Thread.current)")
defer {AppData.funcStack.popToss()}
```

Project-level find and replace makes this easy to maintain so long as I don't touch one without touching them all. If I later comment out the print statement project-wide to declutter the console, I can still access the 'function scope' hierarchy by printing `AppData.funcStack`.

Also, note that the `.getLastPath()` function is a custom extension to the String class so I don't have to write `String("foo/bar/some/Path.swift".split(separator: "/").last!)` to get `"Path.swift"`.